# Looking for part number of 0.05 pitch of SWD and STDC14 headers

Tags: connector, components, pin-headers

I'm looking for pin headers for SWD/JTAG and STDC-14 (SWD + VCP) interfaces.
The ones that can be used together with a STD14 cable from STLink V3 mini.

I found the 10-pin connector that I need on [digikey](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/adafruit-industries-llc/4048/9843412?s=N4IgjCBcoLQdIDGUAuAnArgUwDQgPZQDa4ArAEwAcIAugL517nEgAsADK9fUA):
[image]

Could anybody help me to identify the part number for a similar part for 14-pin connector? Like on this board:
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the following parts (with the key in the middle and without sides) for soldering on the target boards:

- Samtec FTSH-107-01-L-DV-K: is the SMD connector with 14 pins (STDC14), however:

  - Samtec FTSH-107-01-L-DV-K-TR is what I found first
  - Samtec FTSH-107-01-L-DV-K-A  is the model as described in STLink V3Set documentation
- Samtec FTSH-105-01-L-DV-K-TR is the SMD connector with 10 pins (ARM10)

Also, I found the following pars for making flat ribbon adapter cables:

- Harwin M50-3300542 (10 pin, 2 rows header)
- Harwin M50-3300742 (14 pin, 2 rows header)
- Harwin ‎M20-1060400 or JST RE-04‎ (4 pin, 1 row cable connector) : for making an adaptor to BluePill

Existing cables:

- STDC14 to STDC14: Samtec FFSD-07-D-05.90-01-N-R

Answer (score -1):

Use the search similar on your item in Digikey, select all the specs you need except no of positions, and hit search, [I got quite a few results](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/filter/rectangular-connectors-headers-male-pins/314?s=N4IgjCBcoGwJxVAYygMwIYBsDOBTANCAPZQDaIALAAxwDMdIAuoQA4AuUIAymwE4CWAOwDmIAL6EAHJMQgUkDDgLEyIOACYArBqasOkbnyGiJaqrPmK8hEpHJh1YWupi6Q7TjwEjxhOBGg5NCxrFTsQZzAYdVo3DwMvY18QTQcLYKUbVVoAdidNWOZ3fUNvE0JUmUDLEOVbcnoaPLiSxJ9TMBy4c2qM0PqQHKp1dRbPI3bCdWGKdIVarPChkbGEiZMxMSA)

Comment: I've seen those. That is not what I need. Those parts are "boxes" (probably a wrong term). I need the part without side walls.